# API for Listing of Youtube Channels under multiple Branded Accounts under a single Google main Account

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Would like assistance in the following task I have in hands:

- List all Youtube Branded Accounts (title and account ID) and all channels underneath (name and channel ID)

  - Each Branded Account may have multiple Channels
  - Example: BrandChannel1 - ID 1231231231231 - Channel1 - ID qwerqweqwee_1
- This needs to be up to date in demand or weekly, as long there is a way to auto-refresh the list
- It will be created a GSheets for it for the purpose of having a single source of truth

  - Later on I will add more accounts and make a filter so duplicate wont happen

I've tried things on [Channels:link API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) from Youtube and I could not manage to make it work for this purpose.

For API functionality I plan to use [this article](https://mixedanalytics.com/knowledge-base/api-connector-integrate-youtube-api-with-google-sheets/) to make it happen.

Any help in this task will be well appreciated!

Comment: try use this plugin it is working good with me
https://codecanyon.net/item/yt-channel-youtube-channel-and-video-details-api-v3-php-class/13746153

Comment: @Abdo-Host I was checking your plugin, first, I am not using a PHP application or hosting anything so i have no idea on how to actually start it
Second, I found no option of getting what I want from the [doc](https://www.tatwerat.com/demo/yt-channel/php-class/documentation/): Getting a list of my YT Branded Accounts with their ID from a single YT Google main Account